# Drupal 7 manual access to FiveStar module

Tags: drupal, drupal-fivestar, drupal-modules

am trying to override the output of my page so I can add some PHP code, but the FiveStar module only give 2 options which is below or above Content. this is causing me problems as I'd like to include it in my HIDE technique, then I can choose where to place it.

e.g. (I hide all my output before rendering Content, then later I can render each as I choose, I cannot find the render for FiveStar Widget)

```
  hide($content['comments']);
  hide($content['links']);
  hide($content['field_location']);
  hide($content['body']);
  hide($content['field_filename']);
  hide($content['fivestar_widget']);

  print render($content);
```

If any one can fill in the blanks for me would be awesome! 
t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place the widget after `<?php print render($content) ?>` you will have to use `<?php hide($content['fivestar_widget_vote']); ?>` before $content is rendered. Otherwise just use     `<?php print render($content['fivestar_widget_vote']); ?>`. If it is before then the printed property will be set to true and it will only be rendered once.

Comment: Mate I could kiss you! Thats exactly what I've been looking for, for days! could you go one step futher and point me in the direction of how I can find these variables. i.e. "fivestar_widget_vote", "links" etc...

Comment: Use the Devel module and you can use the dsm($vars) function to print the variables to the screen. I use the PhpED IDE which costs a couple of hundred dollars but really makes debugging and development a snap.